# Problems with methods calling methods in a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why aren't these methods working as I expect? I can get a line to print right after
the method, however, none of the other functionality seems to work.

I'm trying to

1. assign a directory
2. iterate over files using glob
3. assign a file handler to each file found in the directory
4. use the method summary which then calls a series of other methods that call each other.
5. Sorting and parsing the file
6. Printing the results of the sorting and parsing.

Code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
#This utility attempts to parse the output text files generated by dcp_inspect
#for faster inspection and when attending to multiple DCP inspections.
#dcp_inspect_parse runs on Python3.x 
import logging
import os
import re
import sys

from glob import glob

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

class DcpParser:
    """Parses DCP Inspector output files, and writes summary files to a
    directory whose path is supplied at construction."""



    def parse(self, dir):
        """Parses all files in the current directory."""
        cpl                  = []
        content              = []
        contentkind          = []
        container            = []
        errors               = [] 
        package              = []
        summary              = []
        mainsound            = []
        mainpicture          = []
        encryption           = []
        duration             = []
        fsp                  = []
        dimensiontype        = []
        aspect               = []
        filesize             = [2]
        audio                = []
        cpltype              = []
        os.chdir(dir)
        files = glob('*')
        logging.debug("Found files: %s", files)
        for file in files:
            try:
                with open(file) as data:
                    logging.debug("Opening file: %s", data)
                    print("Scanning...\t\t\t", file)
                    for each_line in data:
                        #self.prints()
                        self.file_summary()
                        #self.audio()

            except:
                pass



    def prints(self):

            print('Container:             \t\t',container.strip())        
            print('CPL Type:              \t\t',cpltype)
            print('Duration:              \t\t',duration.strip(','))
            print('Frame Rate:            \t\t',fps)
            print('Aspect Ratio:          \t\t',aspect.strip(','))
            print('Dimension:             \t\t',dimensiontype.strip(',')) 
            print('Content Title:         \t\t',content.strip(',').strip('""'))
            print('Audio for DCP:         \t\t', audio)
            print('Package size:          \t\t',filesize)
            print('Encryption status:     \t\t',encryption.upper().strip())       
            print('CPL ID:                \t\t', cpl[2])  
            print('Content Kind:          \t\t',contentkind.upper()) 
            print('\n')
            print('There are',errors[1],'Errors and',errors[3],'hints for', content.strip(','))
            if errors[1] != '0':
                print('could be issues\n')
            else:
                print('This DCP appears to be OK\n')       


    def file_summary(self):
        print('made it to summary')
        self.file_audio()
        for each_line in data:
            if 'summary'in each_line:
                summary.extend(each_line.split())
                print(summary.extend(each_line.split()))
                for x in range(len(summary)):
                    if 'fps' in summary[x]:
                        fps = summary[(x-1)]
                        duration = summary[(x-2)].strip()

                    elif 'summary:' in summary[x]:
                        content = summary[(x+1)]
                        content.strip(',')

                    elif '2D' in summary[x]:
                        dimensiontype = summary[(x)]
                        aspect = summary[(x+1)].strip(',')

                    elif '3D' in summary[x]:
                        dimensiontype = summary[(x)]
                        aspect = summary[(x+1)]

            elif 'Errors' in each_line:
                errors=(each_line.split())
            elif 'Package with total size'in each_line:
                if 'Bytes 0' in each_line:
                    pass
                else:
                    temp =[]
                    temp.extend(each_line.split())
                    filesize=(temp.pop()+' '+temp.pop())


    def file_audio(self):
         print('made it to audio')
         self.file_picture()
         for each_line in data:

             if 'MainSound'in each_line:

                if 'audio' in each_line:
                    m = re.search('([0-9]+)bps', each_line)
                    if m is None:
                        bps = 'bps error'
                    else:
                        bps = int(m.group(1))

                    m = re.search('([0-9]+)ch', each_line)
                    if m is None:
                        channels = 'channel error'
                    else:
                        channels = int(m.group(1))

                    m = re.search('([0-9]+)kHz', each_line)
                    if m is None:
                        bandwidth = 'bandwidth error'
                    else:
                        bandwidth = int(m.group(1))

                    audio = '%ich %ikHz %ibps' % (channels, bandwidth, bps)


    def file_picture(self):
        print('made it to picture')
        for each_line in data:

            if 'MainPicture'in each_line:
               if 'pictures' in each_line:
                   temp = []
                   temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                   container = temp[-2]
                   encryption= temp[-3]




    def file_cplId(self):
        print('cpl id')
        if 'CPL Id:'in each_line:
            cpl=(each_line.split())


    def file_cplType(self):
        if 'CPL type: 'in each_line:
            cpltype=(each_line.split())
            cpltype = cpltype[2]

    def file_contentKind(self):
        if 'ContentKind: 'in each_line:
            contentkind=(each_line.split())
            contentkind = contentkind[1]

    def file_contentTitleText(self):
        if 'ContentTitleText:'in each_line:
            content=(each_line.split(':'))
            content = content[1]










if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Input directory name: " + os.getcwd())
    default_dir = os.getenv('HOME') + '/Desktop/dcp_output'
    prompt = "Please enter the output directory name [" + default_dir + "]: "
    dir = input(prompt) or default_dir
    print("Output directory name: " + dir)

    parser = DcpParser()

    parser.parse(dir )
```

Comment: Any chance you could narrow it down just a little? Try reading http://sscce.org

Comment: "Why aren't these methods working as I expect?"  Can you please explain what you expect, and what is actually happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems strange to me that none of your variables start with `self.` which means that you do not have any class members, all variables are local in the respective method.

Also conveniently you used `try except pass` around the main portion of your code which will ignore any error happening. One of these errors would be that you access `data` in several methods which is neither a global variable nor assigned to previously in the method.

Remove `try except pass` for debug purposes and report what happens.

Comment: You're right. Data is giving me grief. So do i just need to declare data ?

Comment: @user1124541 I guess it should be a class member, in that case you need to use `self.data` instead of `data`.

Comment: How do i make the class members accessible to all functions/methods?

Comment: @user1124541 By using `self.variablename` everywhere.

Comment: added self.var. However, i was using things like strip() on some of the lists. And now that doesn't seem to work on members of my class. How do folks deal with that?

Comment: @user1124541 You mean for example `container.strip()` which now is `self.container.strip()`? Well initially you define `container` as a list: `self.container = []`. `strip()` only works on strings.